# how do you transfer and save data from one view controller to another

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to move data from one view controller to another while also saving that data in the second view controller.

I have seen apps do this quite regularly, but I simply cannot figure out how to transfer AND save the data.

Comment: where u want to save data ?

Comment: in the view controller that I am sending the data

Comment: @karthik In the view controller that I am sending the data,

Comment: I cannot understand your issue , please update your question with some examples or images .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/StoryboardSegue.html) or [delegates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) or [NSNotoification](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/) for passing data

Answer (score 0):

Using NSUserDefaults, we can transfer data from one viewcontroller to another viewcontroller.